# Error Cache.php

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

can anyone give me a support how I can fix a error from the Cache?

I get the error:

```
2016-03-08T08:58:07+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Array to string conversion  in /data/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php on line 403
2016-03-08T08:58:07+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Array to string conversion  in /data/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php on line 403
2016-03-08T08:58:07+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Array to string conversion  in /data/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php on line 403
2016-03-08T08:58:07+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Array to string conversion  in /data/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php on line 403
2016-03-08T08:58:07+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Array to string conversion  in /data/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php on line 403
2016-03-08T08:58:07+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Array to string conversion  in /data/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php on line 403
```

Line 403 in my Cache.php

```
}
return $this->getFrontend()->save((string)$data, $this->_id($id), $this->_tags($tags), $lifeTime);
}
```